# Stream Multiple channels using VLC

Tags: video-streaming, vlc

I have a DVB-T stick, I am able to use VLC to stream a channel and then access it on another computer on my LAN. Now I want that my VLC (on server) can stream different channels using same single DVB-T Stick on different ports of my server. On the client side when user change the port number, they would be able to access different channels. I tried many times to achieve this functionality (by running multiple instances of VLC and changing the frequency and port number on server) but it doesnt allow me to run two VLC same time using one DVB-Stick. Please guide me how can I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need as many receivers as you want to view streams simultaneously. I know that some set-top boxes have two receivers, so that you can watch two streams picture-in-picture or record one stream while watching another, but I don't know about USB sticks. And even if there are USB sticks with multiple receivers, I highly doubt they will have more than two.

So, you will need one receiver for every stream, which probably means one USB stick for every stream.

Comment: well I dont know why its closed, anyway u was right, i am able to achieve the required functionality using multiple ideas